# How i can check my sintax procedure for MARIADB

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I write a procedure for MariaDB. I need to verify correct code.

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE verifyInsert (IN value TINYTEXT)
BEGIN
    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT `table1`.Column1 FROM `table1`
    WHERE `column1` = valore)
    then INSERT INTO `table1`(`column1`) VALUES (value)
    END IF;
END;
// DELIMITER;
```

This procedure must be verify if an inserted value is present. 
If yes i do not anything else it insert in my database.
Someone could verify my code please?

Comment: If you do not want to add duplicate values to a given field, then create a unique index on it, not complex code that can be circumvented.

Comment: is `valore` a string or a column-name?  Or maybe a typo for `value`?

Answer (score 0):

As said, make unique column. And you can use

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO
```

so you just "eat" the error and go on as planned.